# How to get the device information from the rs2::pipeline object?

Tags: realsense

I have a function which takes in rs2::pipeline as a parameter and I have multiple D435 & T265 trying to access that function. I want to display different information according to the camera that is calling that function so how can I get the information about the camera through the rs2::pipeline object.

The rs2::device has a method for get_info gives the information about the camera but I am not sure how to reference rs2::device from the rs2::pipeline.

```
void RenderCamera(rs2::pipeline pipe,int id){
    //Display the camera information here from the rs2::pipeline object
    ...
    ...
    ...
    imshow("Rendered_Window",frame_mat);

}
```

The result I want to see around here is a simple debug statement which gives me the information of the device.

Answer (score 0):

`rs::device` is required to get the device information, below is one way of getting the camera info. For this device need to start and stop capturing, which is overhead and can cause some side effects if the device is already started capturing. Always keep in mind the context of calling `RenderCamera` function.

```cpp
    void RenderCamera(rs2::pipeline pipe,int id){    
         rs2::config config;             
         rs2::pipeline_profile pipeline_profile = pipeline.start(config); // camera starts capturing
         pipeline_profile = pipeline.start(config);
         rs2::device rs_dev = pipeline_profile.get_device();
         std::cout <<"Device Name"<<": "<< rs_dev.get_info(RS2_CAMERA_INFO_NAME)<<std::endl;
         std::cout <<"Firmware Version"<<": "<<rs_dev.get_info(RS2_CAMERA_INFO_FIRMWARE_VERSION)<<std::endl;
         std::cout <<"Serial Number"<<": "<<rs_dev.get_info(RS2_CAMERA_INFO_SERIAL_NUMBER)<<std::endl;
         std::cout <<"Product Id"<<": "<<rs_dev.get_info(RS2_CAMERA_INFO_PRODUCT_ID)<<std::endl;
         pipeline.stop(); // camera stops capturing     
         ----   
         ----    
    }
```